# CodeIgniter fetching data from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

hey I am new to codeigniter. I am having problems in fetching data from my database here is my getOne function

```
public function getOne($sku){

    $ans = 0;
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM barcode_sku WHERE sku = "$sku"');
    $res = $query->result();
    $row = $res[0];
    $ans =  $row->quantity;


    return $ans;
}
```

the variable $sku will have values like bc_001 or bc_002.... The problem is if I hard code this value i.e bc_001 in my query it fetches the result correctly however when I use the variable $sku in my query it does not work. please help.

Comment: I have to ask, are you sure that $sku is getting set correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using single quotes to warp your query statement php will not prase the variable inside that query,  instead use the double quotations to allow php to interpret the $sku variable.

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM barcode_sku WHERE sku = \"$sku\"");
```

Also don't forget  to escape $sky variable  to avoid SQL Injections.

a better solution is to  use codeigniter active record.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

may be you can modify the query like this:

```
public function getOne($sku){

    $ans = 0;
    $sql= 'SELECT * FROM barcode_sku WHERE sku = ?';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($sku));
    $res = $query->result();
    $row = $res[0];
    $ans =  $row->quantity;


    return $ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this --

```
public function getOne($sku)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('barcode_sku');
    $this->db->like('sku ', $sku,'after');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

it will return a array..